# Why Rh conflict happen but no ABO conflicts?

Tags: immunology, antibody, red-blood-cell

I wonder why Rhesus conflict can happen during pregnancy and mother can make antibodies against Rh protein (I think the correct name is D protein), but it doesn't happen if mother has different ABO type than the child?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It happens](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABO_blood_group_system#Disease_risks), but it is very rare.

**Anti-A** and **Anti-B** antibodies are IgM type. They **do no cross the placenta**. Sometimes IgG can be produced and lead to the hemolytic disease of the newborn.

**Anti-D** antibodies [are IgG type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhesus_blood_group_system#Hemolytic_disease_of_the_newborn) and **can pass through the placenta**.